# Error Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I am following a tutorial on YouTube, but I'm stuck at (+/- 41 min)(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuo3n-DjF7w). I'm expected to see a indication when I click on a menu item, but this doesn't happen. The picture below shows how it's supposed to look:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQsXf.png)

how it should look: Navigation drawer tutorial Main Code:

```
package com.example.flori.mylordring;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{


    private static ImageButton imgView;
    private int test;
    int [] images = {R.drawable.im1,R.drawable.im2,R.drawable.im3,R.drawable.im4,R.drawable.im5,R.drawable.im6,R.drawable.im7};
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView navList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navlist);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ArrayList<String> navArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        navArray.add("Home");
        navArray.add("Fragment 1");
        navArray.add("Fragment 2");
        navArray.add("Fragment 3");
        navArray.add("Fragment 4");
        navArray.add("Fragment 5");
        navList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,navArray);
        navList.setAdapter(adapter);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.opendrawer,R.string.closedrawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Rolololo", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle saveInstancesState){
        super.onPostCreate(saveInstancesState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }


    public void image(View view){
       imgView=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           test++;
                                           test = test % images.length;
                                           imgView.setImageResource(images[test]);
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navList)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
            }else{
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(navList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your onItemClick method, you are breaking out of every case without anything and you implemented OnItemClickListener interface, nothing will happen if you do not specify what should happen in those cases. Please specify what you want in those cases instead of breaking out. You might add a toast to see what's going on,

like case 0: `Toast.makeText(yourContext, "first item", Toast.LENGTH SHORT).show();
break;`

Comment: Yes i aggree with you but on the tutorial, code is the same as mine but him,  when he clicks it done like on the picture.